# Fatal Error on a WordPress page: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

After updating all of our plugins and WordPress, we're receiving this error on one of our webpages:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id() on a non-object in /home/dbooth1/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 57

I've tried searching for similar issues, but none of the fixes thus far have proven effective.  I suspect that the problem lies in the page template.

One of the more promising suggestions on the web was to replace

```
$wp_query= null;
```

with:

```
wp_reset_query();
```

But that didn't make a difference. What else could be the problem?

Edit: Link to the page's template code: http://pastebin.com/P5HQCP3Y

Comment: I think the template code would be useful.  Are you calling a function that's missing `global $wp_query;` at the top?  Why are you setting `$wp_query` to null?

Comment: Okay, I've added a link to the template in the main post. The original template was made long ago by someone I've never met, and it's been edited by numerous other folks before me :)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code you've pasted, so I suspect the problem's in either `get_post_top_ancestor_id()` or `mytheme_page_navi()` (since you haven't given a full stack trace).  Can you post the code for them?  And maybe a full stack trace of the error?